# How to select values from a column which name is a reserved word (data type)?

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

I have the following view with columns:

```
TYPE    VARCHAR2(10)
NUMER   VARCHAR2(10)
```

and when I try to select the data, I get the `ORA-00936: missing expression` error, because the compiler thinks that columns are actually the data types. So, how to select the data from that columns?

Comment: can you show us your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use double quotes in the query -

```
select "TYPE", "NUMBER"
 from table_name
```

Comment: And I'm curios how could @Tony create table or view with column names he can't query.

Comment: @diziaq - the same, way, by having the names quoted in the `create view` statement.

Comment: @Alex I allude to it. The author says "I have the following view with columns" and this implies he saw the view description. So he could just put the same (quoted) column names into SELECT.

Comment: @diziaq I think its gui. In the ide interface you can see TYPE    VARCHAR2(10), but column description in the database will be double qouted.

Answer (score -1):

You tried to execute a SQL statement but you omitted a part of the syntax.

You should use syntax properly
 SELECT COL1,COL2....COLN FROM TABLE_NAME
                WHERE COL = CONDITION